# Google Cloud Instance Not able to Connect through Putty - Getting "Not Supported Authentication Methods Available (server sent : public key)"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, putty, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I am new to Google Cloud, but I have followed all the steps below by looking at some documentations and forums. Not sure if I am missing anything with the configuration or what. Any help would be appreciated

- Created Instance on Google Cloud
- Downloaded PuttyGen and generated key
- Updated key on instance as well as Project metadata as well
- Trying to connect from Putty I am getting following error

[image]
Not sure what is happening. I have tried all help from other posts from stackoverflow and google groups as well. But nothing seems to change for me. It could be simple that I am not looking at?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Apologies Martin. Will take care next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to follow your steps and found no issues.

Please have a look at the commands below:

- create test VM instance;
- [download](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html) PuTTY and PuTTYgen ;
- follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys) and generate SSH keys:

  > 3. Click Generate and follow the on-screen instructions to generate a new key. For most cases, the default parameters are fine, but you must
  >    generate keys with at least 2,048 bits. When you have finished
  >    generating the key, the tool displays your public key value.
  > 4. *In the **Key comment** section, replace the existing text with the username of the user for whom you will apply the key.*
  >    [image: puttygen]
  > 5. Optionally, you can enter a **Key passphrase** to protect your key.
  > 6. Click **Save private key** to write your private key to a file with a `.ppk` extension.
  > 7. Click **Save public key** to write your public key to a file for later use. Keep the PuTTYgen window open for now.
- follow the documentation [Adding or removing project-wide public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide) to add public key project wide at the [Metadata](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/metadata/sshKeys?) page:

  > Use project-wide public SSH keys to give users general access to a
  > Linux instance. Project-wide public SSH keys give users access to all
  > of the Linux instances in a project that allow project-wide public SSH
  > keys. If an instance blocks project-wide public SSH keys, a user can't
  > use their project-wide public SSH key to connect to the instance
  > unless the same public SSH key is also added to instance metadata.
  > [image: ssh_key_metadata]

  or follow documentation [Adding or removing instance-level public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only) to do it at the instance level:

  > Instance-level public SSH keys give users access to a specific Linux
  > instance. Users with instance-level public SSH keys can access a Linux
  > instance even if it blocks project-wide public SSH keys.
  > [image: ssh_key_instance]
- add private key to PuTTY and connect to VM instance using username you use at the **Key comment** section while generating the key, **I was able to reproduce your error by using any other username at this step**.

In addition, have a look at the [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) feature:

> OS Login lets you use Compute Engine IAM roles to grant or revoke SSH
> access to your Linux instances. OS Login is an alternative to managing
> instance access by adding and removing SSH keys in metadata.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answers. I have followed the same steps. Except I am not sure what is OS Login. is there alternative way to SSH through third party client? We want to make it through third party client like Putty, WinSCP or bitvise. But not able to get success from any of the client. Is there something I am missing? Is OS Login enable is mandatory? Do we need to create a user first in Linux and then create SSH key? I know it's weird questions but need to get more clarity on this. I worked with AWS and Digital Ocean and they are pretty straight forward. Google Cloud seems tough.

Comment: **1**. Have a look at the pictures provided in the documentation and be sure that you use the same username while generating SSH key, adding them to the Metadata or to the instance properties and logging to the instance. I was able to reproduce your issue with wrong username. **2**. There's no need to create user in advance. **3**. Please update your question with screenshot s of your configuration to make me able to check them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to connect with just one change in the step. As per document with key generation it is mentioned that change "key comment" and save public and private key. I didn't change default and it worked successfully. What could be the reason? If I have to change "key comment'" to familiar name what should I do wit PuttyGen?

Comment: You can leave default value of `Key comment`, but in this case you should use it as your `username`accordingly to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys) : "In the **Key comment** section, replace the existing text with the username of the user for whom you will apply the key.". It's recommended to change it to more convenient value. To do it, you can put there `username` you'd like to use for login to your VM instance while generating keys with PuTTYgen.

Comment: Please upvote/accept my answer if it was helpful for you.

Comment: I think there may be a maximum length to the Key comment. My original one was 40 characters long. I kept trying it wondering why I was getting the same error as above. When I reduced the size, I was able to connect.